# How to display ^M as newline in vim?

Tags: vim, line-breaks

I would like to display ^M (\r) as newlines (\n) in vim. The file has both \r and \n characters. I would like to do this without:

- Editing the file
- Changing the way existing \n characters are displayed
- Having to do a search and replace every time I open the file

In short, the same way Notepad++ displays them.